# NuGet dependency for local projects

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .net 6 solution with a huge number of projects, every project will be publish as a NuGet package to be used by other teams.
Some of the projects depends from others project of the solution.

I’m already scared of how complicated an time consuming will be the switch to package dependency    for local development.

For every fix it will be necessary to:

- modify one or more projects
- build them, create and publish updated packages
- update dependency in other project
- repeat all if something went wrong

I’m wondering if it’s possible to mantain locally a project dependency that became a package dependency with publication.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"I’m wondering if it’s possible to maintain locally a project dependency that became a package dependency with publication." Yes, sure. That's automatically the case.

By default, a nuget contains only a single dll, so any reference to another dll (be that an external one or one in the same solution) will become a dependency of that package.

Comment: To confirm: if you have two projects, A and B and A references B as a `.csproj`, then A and B will both automatically end up as Nuget packages with the A package referencing the B package?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama That is correct, at least as far as I'm aware. You can check the dependencies of a nuget package by using a tool such as the NugetPackageExplorer if you are unsure.